# Are all USB numeric keypads OSX comatible?

Tags: keyboard, usb

My office uses the small Apple bluetooth keyboards.  I have a user who is requesting a numeric keypad.  Apple sells a [Belkin wireless keypad](http://store.apple.com/us/product/HD389VC/A/belkin-yourtype-bluetooth-wireless-keypad?fnode=56) on their website, but it has terrible reviews and it isnt cheap.

There are countless USB numeric keypads that are a fraction of the price, all designed for Windows.

If I buy one of the USB ones, it should work on a Mac, right?  It is just a USB keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it's just a normal keyboard input device, which it should be.
I have one which doesn't say it's specifically for OS X, but works fine—it's just a keyboard.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but Im new to supporting Apple products and I wasnt 100% sure...

Comment: @Keltari Unless it's something special, it should work fine. It's impossible to know without testing the specific device, but all the ones I've seen (including the one I have) work fine as they are just a keyboard with a limited set of buttons.

Comment: good enough for me.  worst case, i can just return it.